# Efficiency of java static method calling

Tags: java, oop

my professor said that when ever i use a static method from a class the whole class gets loaded into memory and then the method is executed.

my question is: if a class contains 100 methods and 50 different variables and if i called one static method from that class.the complete class(100 methods and 50 variable ) gets loaded in memory which is inefficient in terms of memory and performance. How does java deals with this kind of issue ?

Comment: Whenever you use **anything** from a class, that whole class gets loaded.

Comment: when class gets loaded all the variable and methods gets loaded or just static variable and static methods gets loaded?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Well, anything at runtime.  An import statement might appear to qualify as 'anything' to someone unfamiliar with the language, and it wouldn't cause a class load.

Comment: @NazeerMohammad one could look at two answers to your question: (1) "only static variables and methods and related stuff" and (2) what difference does it make?  These worries about 'efficiency' usually turn out to be worth very little, especially in the abstract.  If you have a specific efficiency problem you want to describe, that's better, but in general a class load triggered by a static method invocation is a good example of something not to worry about.

Comment: Loading a class is almost always super cheap compared to actually doing any work with your code.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: There are exceptions, e.g. the use of a static final String field initialized with a String literal does not cause the class to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True, the class byte-code is loaded when you call a `static` method (but *once*, not *every time*).. The same also happens when you call a non-static method. In the later case an instance also must be created. Thus, in the sense of your question,  it is a false dichotomy. Because Java is a dynamic language and platform (with a JIT) the runtime efficiency can increase significantly between method invocations. Thus, it is best to write clear and concise code (that is [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html)). If the clearest way to implement your solution is `static` methods then use them.